# Unsatisfied link error: Android JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm working on a Android project which uses JNI. After 2 days of debugging, i still get an error: An unsatisfied link error:

**Java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.samples.facedetect.Hello.sayHello:()V**

There are many people who have had this problem before, so i have read and tried many possible solutions but i still can't get it to work :(

My code:

**Hello.java** =

```
public class Hello { 

    public static native void sayHello(); 

    static {
        Log.i("JNI", "Loading hello");
        System.loadLibrary("hello");
    }
}
```

**Hello_jni.cpp** =

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <Hello_jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define LOG_TAG "FaceDetection/DetectionBasedTracker"
#define LOGD(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))

extern "C"  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_facedetect_Hello_sayHello
 (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj)
{
 printf("Hello world!\n");
 LOGD("werkt");
 return;
}
```

**Hello_jni.h** =

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class org_opencv_samples_facedetect_Hello */

#ifndef _Included_org_opencv_samples_facedetect_Hello
#define _Included_org_opencv_samples_facedetect_Hello
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     org_opencv_samples_facedetect_Hello
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_facedetect_Hello_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**Android.mk** = (first part is for other module from openCV. I'm using the facedetection example from openCV as template for my application)

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
#OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=off
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := hello
LOCAL_SRC_FILE := org_opencv_samples_facedetect_Hello_jni.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

from my main activity, i call Hello.sayHello() (static). This triggers the error. 
Tried:
- Removing/adding 'Extern "C"' to sayHello() in the cpp file.
- Change function from native to not-native

The library seems to load fine, this is the whole error:

```
I/JNI(21440): Hello.sayHello() called
I/JNI(21440): Loading hello
D/dalvikvm(21440): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.opencv.samples.facedetect/lib/libhello.so 0x4248c960
D/dalvikvm(21440): Added shared lib /data/data/org.opencv.samples.facedetect/lib/libhello.so 0x4248c960
D/dalvikvm(21440): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.opencv.samples.facedetect/lib/libhello.so 0x4248c960, skipping init
W/dalvikvm(21440): No implementation found for native Lorg/opencv/samples/facedetect/Hello;.sayHello:()V
D/AndroidRuntime(21440): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(21440): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a4e2a0)
E/AndroidRuntime(21440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(21440): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.samples.facedetect.Hello.sayHello:()V
E/AndroidRuntime(21440):    at     org.opencv.samples.facedetect.Hello.sayHello(Native Method)
```

If anybody can help me out, you would be a hero! I just can't get it to work...

Thanks in advance :)

Jelmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now, the problem was the Android.mk file. Thanks Vorren for giving the solution ;)
The working make file is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
#OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=off
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Hello_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog 

LOCAL_MODULE := hello

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

there were two errors; syntax error LOCAL_SRC_FILE (missing the S), and i called 'my-dir' 2 times in the make file, which is prohibited (found this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/Qmr_WQH-uKk)

Answer (score 1):

Your dalvik runtime tells you exactly what is wrong:

`W/dalvikvm(21440): No implementation found for native Lorg/opencv/samples/facedetect/Hello;.sayHello:()V
D/AndroidRuntime(21440): Shutting down VM`

Which means that you haven't properly implemented your native method and java runtime can't find it. Such error occurs in runtime only, the lib compiles ok, which gives me a hunch, that either method name (in .h and .cpp file) is wrong and doesn't correspond to the jni naming format, or that there is an error in .cpp file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that dalvik can't find the called method, but i don't know why. I've copied the auto-generated function name from the header file and it doesn't contain any underscores (which is prohibited). I've been looking at the code for hours, without any result.

Comment: Do you compile your Hello_jni.cpp? It's not included in Android.mk.

Comment: Vorren, ow yes! Thats true. Thanks for pointing out. I changed the name from Hello.cpp to Hello_jni.cpp a while ago but forgot to change it in Android.mk too. 

I changed it and recompiled the code, but sadly it didn't had any effect, still the same error.

I also tried to change 'org_opencv_samples_facedetect_Hello_jni.cpp' to Hello_jni.cpp, just like the detection_based_tracker module (which works, openCV example) but still no luck

Comment: Hmm. LOCAL_SRC_FILE should be LOCAL_SRC_FILES. ndk-build command should list out the files it passes to the compiler - does your file get compiled?

Comment: Also true! I didn't expect there were so many errors in the make file. The ndk-build command worked before and it sputt out a libhello.so in the libs/(platform) folder.

However, now i changed FILE to FILES, i get an error when executing the ndk-build command. I will look into the error!
    make.exe: *** No rule to make target `C:/Users/Jelmer/Downloads/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/android-ndk32-r10-windows-x86/android-ndk-r10/build/core/Hello_jni.cpp', needed by `obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hello/Hello_jni.o'.  Stop.

Comment: no rule to make target usually means that the file you're passing to the compiler doesn't exist. You should specify the exact path to the file you wish to compile. Something like $(LOCAL_PATH)/Hello_jni.cpp (if the file is in /jni directory of your project, otherwise supply appropriate path). should do the trick. Also you should define LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) - it will ensure that your linker can see your .h files in the /jni directory.

Comment: Vorren! You are a hero! Finally i got it working. I had to change the Android.mk file a little bit (remove one 'call my dir'; i found out it only can be called once in a make file) I will add the solution as answer. Thank you very very much ;)